# Is there a way to list put which repositories the dependency jars are coming from?

Tags: maven

Our company has our own Nexus Repository. New dependency jars have to be approved before adding to the repository. I have a project that I need to upgrade the versions of the jars. In doing, I have to list out all the new jars, their versions and transient dependency jars for review and upload. Is there a way to generate such a list base on the updated pom.xml? For example, if A-1.jar depends on B-1.jar and C-1.jar, and B-1 is available in our Nexus repository, we will only need to ask for A-1.jar and C-1.jar to be uploaded.

Comment: not sure how you plan to work. There are tow plugins available that may help with this task, but both retrieve the newer versions from repositories they need to be able to reach. First is the dependency plugin, for example the goal: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/list-repositories-mojo.html - second is the versions plugin with: https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/dependency-updates-report-mojo.html - both contain more goals that might are closer to what you need.